# SAS: update dataset if it exists, else create it

Tags: if-statement, sas, exists

I need to update a dataset mylib.dt_old  using the dataset dt_new, but I want to first check if it actually exists, otherwise I would get an error. In case it does not exist, I just want to create a dataset mylib.dt_old that stores the information contained in dt_new. 
I tried the following:

```
if (exist(mylib.dt_old)) 
then do;
  data   mylib.dt_old;
  update mylib.dt_old  dt_new;
  by date var1 var2; 
  run;
end;
else do;
  data mylib.dt_old;  set dt_new;
  run;
end;
```

However I get the error, when mylib.dt_old does not exist

```
ERROR: File MYLIB.DT_OLD.DATA does not exist.
```

and sas goes on actually executing the else statement (creates dt_old copying dt_new).

Instead if dt_old does exist I get

```
   if (exist(mylib.dt_old))
   --
   180
   ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

What am I doing wrong?
PS: I am a beginner in SAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do would actually qualify as macro programming in SAS, which is sometimes considered an "advanced" topic.

The normal if-then control logic you're using is what SAS considers data-step code, i.e. it's only valid in the data step.  But there is a "macro" language that looks similar, but is distinguished by `%` prefixes.  Here's how your modified code might look:

```
%macro updater();
    %if %sysfunc(exist(mylib.dt_old)) 
    %then %do;
        data   mylib.dt_old;
            update mylib.dt_old  dt_new;
            by date var1 var2; 
        run;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        data mylib.dt_old;
            set dt_new;
        run;
    %end;
%mend updater;
%updater()
```

While this example is sort-of straightforward, the SAS macro language is frequently counterintuitive (to me at least).  If you're a beginner it might be a good idea to find and read an "into to SAS macros" online.

Comment: Many thanks, it works perfectly. As you said, at least coming from simpler analytical languages like R, matlab etc., it seems pretty counterintuitive that a macro is needed to use an IF control.